# How to compile libass to iOS platform?

Tags: ios, cross-compiling, subtitle, build-script

I want to render .ass file to display subtitles, but I don't know how to cross-compile it.

Github repo is here:

https://github.com/libass/libass

I'm looking for some build scripts kind of things, anybody can help? Thanks.